# VB NET combobox and textbox response message after click

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, messagebox

how can I output messagebox after I clicked combobox or textbox which both controls are in disable condition.
Any methods will be appreciated !
Thanks you

Comment: You can't, how about using other validation?

Comment: Can I use mouse click event ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: You can use my basic approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17498437/2330053), and check to see if the cursor is contained by either of those controls at the time of the click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form MouseDown event:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown

  If TextBox1.Enabled = False AndAlso _
     e.X >= TextBox1.Left And e.X <= TextBox1.Left + TextBox1.Width AndAlso _
     e.Y >= TextBox1.Top And e.Y <= TextBox1.Top + TextBox1.Height Then
    MsgBox("The textbox is disabled")
  End If

  If ComboBox1.Enabled = False AndAlso _
     e.X >= ComboBox1.Left And e.X <= ComboBox1.Left + ComboBox1.Width AndAlso _
     e.Y >= ComboBox1.Top And e.Y <= ComboBox1.Top + ComboBox1.Height Then
    MsgBox("The combobox is disabled")
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine in textbox, but why it does not work in combobox control ?

Comment: I just tried it and it works OK. Be sure and put both cases in a single handler. I've just modified my answer to show this.